# How to Execute (Vector) Storage.getInstance().readObject(filePath); in Java 8 Swing Package

Tags: codenameone

[image]Windows 10 Pro
Latest Simulator
Java Swing Project

I would like to execute "Vector a1 = (Vector) Storage.getInstance().readObject(filePath);"
In a Java Swing Application running on Windows 10 platform, I tried import CodenameOne.jar in Swing package, however when executing above code, get null pointer exception in Storage.getInstance()

Is there a way to execute this in Swing?

Thoughts?

Best Regards.

Thanks, I did not init the Display, however "Display.init(Object m)" requires an Object Argument and the Init method is deprecated.

Can you please provide me the codenameone Display dependencies?
And perhaps a java Swing snippet of code to initialize Display in order to execute Storage.getInstance().readObject(filePath)

Thoughts?

Best Regards

Thanks, Passing init(working directory) solved the Exception thrown.
Here is the Code snippet used to allow me to execute:
Storage.getInstance().readObject(filePath).

```
    String filePath = incSrv.Pwd();// gets working directory
    try {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Display.init(filePath);
                String fileName = "A1-MMA.properties";
                Vector a1 = (Vector) Storage.getInstance().readObject(filePath);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

And it does appear to work,
However I am left with a blacked out form that appears modal.
How can I avoid this or dispose it?.

FYI: What I am creating here is a work around for serializing Vector in Codenameone. I Save Vector to file using "Storage.getInstance().writeObject(Path, Vector)"
I convert the file to bytes and write it to the Swing Server VIA socket.
Using Storage.getInstance().readObject(file) on the Swing Server I have deserialize the object into the Vector from my app.
This appears to work well and is more efficient than the current method I use to deliver complex Vectors from the app to the Swing Server.

Can you please let me know if you see a red flag with this workaround?
Like The ability to Storage.getInstance().readObject(file) on the Swing Server may go away?
This method will save a lot of time in movind Vector data to and from the App/Server.

Thoughts Best Regards

```
Storage.getInstance().readObject(file) // (A1ServiceSrv.java:571)
Caused this Exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.io.Storage.init(Storage.java:89)
at com.codename1.io.Storage.getInstance(Storage.java:112)
at Main.A1ServiceSrv.loadVectorFromFile(A1ServiceSrv.java:571)
```

Regards

12/11/2021:
Thanks Shai,

I am including in my classpath CodenameOne.jar with update date of 12/11/2021 after CN1 refresh.
Getting Same null pointer exception.
Passing in Path "C:\Src1\A1-Arms\A1-Server\A1-MMA.properties" (Absolute Path)
Also Tried "A1-MMA.properties", however I don't think Codenameone knows where my home path is since we are not initializing it as we did with

```
    Display.init("Current Working Directory where files reside");
```

This is the Fresh Stack Trace w/o calling Display.init (12-20-2021)
java.lang.NullPointerException  at

```
com.codename1.ui.Display.getResourceAsStream(Display.java:3086)
        at com.codename1.io.Log.print(Log.java:327)
        at com.codename1.io.Log.logThrowable(Log.java:299)
        at com.codename1.io.Log.e(Log.java:285)
        at com.codename1.io.Storage.readObject(Storage.java:271)
        at Main.A1ServiceSrv.loadVectorFromFile(A1ServiceSrv.java:596)
            
            vector = (Vector) Storage.getInstance().readObject(filePath); // (A1ServiceSrv.java:596)
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the exception. I'm guessing you're missing `Display.init()` in your code which is necessary to initialize Codename one.

Comment: Thanks, I did not init the Display, however "Display.init(Object m)" requires an Object Argument and the Init method is deprecated.

Can you please provide me the codenameone Display dependencies? And perhaps a java Swing snippet of code to initialize Display in order to execute Storage.getInstance().readObject(filePath)

Thoughts?

Best Regards

Comment: It's deprecated since it's for internal use. In the case of desktop build you need to use it. Give it a string representing your home directory. But what's the stack of the exception?

Comment: Please see my Updated Response.

Comment: OK, if this solves the problem and all you need is "storage" let's take a step back for a second. If you don't do the display.init() what's the stack trace for the null pointer exception?

Comment: Please see my Updated Response

Comment: Please see my Updated Response

Comment: I made the change on Saturday and this jar is from the Friday release. Notice the stack is identical. You can try building from code or you can look in the Actions tab in github to see if there's an artifact you can use that's up to date.

Comment: I made the changes:

Comment: FYI you mistakenly tried to edit my response instead of the question. Notice the implementation is null in your case. But line 89 will never fail since we do a null check there. If it appears in your stack you have a version prior to the fix

Comment: Please see fresh stack trace :This is the Fresh Stack Trace w/o calling Display.init (12-20-2021) java.lang.NullPointerException at

Comment: This is a stack trace from a rethrow it's missing the contents of the other stack trace before that.  Essentially it means Log failed which I can understand. I suggest just running it in a debugger with exception tracing turned on. You should see where an exception is thrown related to our code.

Answer (score 0):

This is hopefully fixed by this commit: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/72bf283bdaaefe5207bb9fd6787578e3ef61522c if not let me know with a fresh stack